# Java testing enum

Tags: java, junit, enums

I looked through the other enum related questions and still can't seem to figure this out.

I have a Position Enum:

```
public enum Position
{
   LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT;
}
```

and a Tower class:

```
public class Tower extends LinkedStack<Disc>
{
    private Position position;

    /**
     * Tower implementation
     * 
     * @param location the location of the tower
     */
    public Tower(Position location)
    {
        super();
        this.position = location;
    }

    /**
     * Position of the tower
     * 
     * @return position the position of the tower
     */
    public Position position()
    {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Push method
     * 
     * @param disc disc to be pushed
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the disc cannot be pushed
     */
    @Override
    public void push(Disc disc)
    {
        Disc last = this.peek();
        if (this.isEmpty() || (last.compareTo(disc)) == 1)
        {
            super.push(disc);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

}
```

The test for tower:

```
private Position LEFT;
private Position MIDDLE;
private Position RIGHT;

private Tower t1;
private Tower t2;
private Tower t3;

/**
 * 
 */
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    LEFT = Position.LEFT;
    MIDDLE = Position.MIDDLE;
    RIGHT = Position.RIGHT;

    t1 = new Tower(LEFT);
    t2 = new Tower(MIDDLE);
    t3 = new Tower(RIGHT);
}

/**
 * Test method for Tower(Position).
 */
@Test
public final void testTower()
{
    Tower t4 = new Tower(LEFT);
}

/**
 * Test method for position().
 */
@Test
public final void testPosition()
{
    assertEquals(LEFT, t1.position());
    assertEquals(MIDDLE, t2.position());
    assertEquals(RIGHT, t3.position());
    assertFalse(t3.position() == LEFT);
}
```

Is there a reason why these assertions are returning null for the position instead of LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT?

Comment: You did `location = position;`, you want `position = location;`. Better yet: `this.position = location;`.

Comment: `assertEquals` that compares a `String` to an `enum` will always return `false`. Use `assertEquals(Position.LEFT, t1.position());` etc. instead.

Comment: `assertFalse(t3.position() == LEFT);` may not work as `LEFT` is defined inside `setUp` method. You should change `LEFT` to `Position.LEFT`

Comment: Those changes helped but now I get a NullPointerException?

Comment: I get the NPE for the testPosition assertions

Comment: So the code is not here... you didn't paste any testPosition method.

Comment: Sorry I meant testTower

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger? Just put a breakpoint in the first line of testTower method and run it in debug mode. Once you hit the breakpoint you can check certain statments return like t1, t1.position() and assertEquals(Position.LEFT, t1.position()). Without this skill you can't be a good programmer. The earlier you master it the better for you.

Comment: The classes have been updated to reflect the changes

Comment: your setup method is not initializing t1, t2 & t3.. so you will get null pointer exceptions... change it to initialize the objects as shown in my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `@Before` annotation before your setUp method.

Comment: the @Before accidentally got cut when I pasted my code over

Answer (score 0):

Either do this one,

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    Position LEFT = Position.LEFT;
    Position MIDDLE = Position.MIDDLE;
    Position RIGHT = Position.RIGHT;

    t1 = new Tower(LEFT);
    t2 = new Tower(MIDDLE);
    t3 = new Tower(RIGHT);
}
```

Or do this,

```
@Test
public final void testTower()
{     
    setup();
    assertEquals("LEFT", t1.position());
    assertEquals("MIDDLE", t2.position());
    assertEquals("RIGHT", t3.position());
    assertFalse(t3.position() == LEFT);
}
```

*Only reason is, t1,t2...so on not initialize because of setUp() not execute.*

Answer (score 0):

your `setUp` method is not correct. Change it to initialize t1, t2 & t3, that should take care of the NPE

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    LEFT = Position.LEFT;
    MIDDLE = Position.MIDDLE;
    RIGHT = Position.RIGHT;

    t1 = new Position(LEFT);
    t2 = new Position(MIDDLE);
    t3 = new Position(RIGHT);
}
```

Comment: He's changing the code every 3 mins -_-. And you also did a mistake as you have t1 repeated 3 times instead of t1, t2, t3 respectively.